# Merging two Multidimensional Arrays into a Multidimensional Array with Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning the new JavaScript ES6 syntax and am trying to create a multidimensional array with objects from 2 other multidimensional arrays. Presumably my syntax is incorrect, but I don't know how to fix it. The result should be:

```js
[
  [{    letter: w,    instances: 1
  }, {  letter: o,    instances: 1
  }, {  letter: d,    instances: 2
  }, {  letter: r,    instances: 1
  }],
  [{    letter: s,    instances: 1
  }, {  letter: y,    instances: 1
  }],
  [{    letter: h,    instances: 1
  }, {  letter: e,    instances: 1
  }, {  letter: l,    instances: 2
  }, {  letter: o,    instances: 1
  }]
]
```

My code uses two map methods:

```js
var letters = [
  ["w", "o", "d", "r"],
  ["s", "y"],
  ["h", "e", "l", "o"]
];
var numbers = [
  [1, 1, 2, 1],
  [1, 1][1, 1, 2, 1]
];
var objArr = letters.map(function(c, i) {
  return c.map(function(c2, i2, a2) {
    return {
      letter: c2,
      instances: numbers[i]
    }
  })
});
console.log(objArr);
```

It correctly returns a multidimensional array with objects and correct letter values, but the number values are incorrect. Can anyone find why this happens? Also, does anyone think there's a better way of storing the letters and the number of numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a two-dimensional array, you need to use two indexes to access it. Use the first index `i`, to access the inner array and the use second index `j`, to access the number inside the array.

```js
let letters = [["w", "o", "d", "r"],["s", "y"],["h", "e", "l", "o"]],
    numbers = [[1, 1, 2, 1],[1, 1],[1, 1, 2, 1]],
    result = letters.map((arr, i) => arr.map((letter, j) => ({letter,instances: numbers[i][j]})));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: one thing I don't understand is this part: {letter,instances: numbers[i][j]} - why wouldn't it be {letter: letter,instances: numbers[i][j]}? how does your code know to assign letter as 'letter'?

Comment: It's object shorthand property names introduced in `ES2015`.

Answer (score 3):

One very small mistake in `instances:` Pls see below

```js
var letters = [["w", "o", "d", "r"],["s", "y"],["h", "e", "l", "o"]];

var numbers = [[1,1,2,1],[1,1], [1,1,2,1]];

var objArr = letters.map(function(c,i) {
                return c.map(function(c2,i2) {
                    return {letter: c2, instances: numbers[i][i2]}
                })
            });

console.log(objArr)
```